# How do I do multiple regression for more than one dependent variable?

Tags: multiple-regression, categorical-data, spss, multivariate-regression

My IV variable is leader's qualities (with five categories) and my DV is school climate (with 6 categories). I would like to test whether my IV variable (with five categories) has an influenced on my DV (with 6 categories). I am thinking of using standard linear multiple regression. But multiple regression in SPSS can only accommodate 1 DV in the box. Do I have to run a multiple regression for each of the 6 DVs separately (with the 6 categories as my IVs).

Comment: You make search **multivariate** regression

Comment: An explanation of categories and coding may facilitate a good answer by users of this site.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds more like you should do a crosstab with a chi-squared or other similar tests.

The point is that you want to treat your dependent variable as nominal or ordinal, so a crosstab, which offers a number of tests of association appropriate for categorical variables seems to be a more appropriate tool.

Comment: This is being automatically flagged as low quality, probably because it is so short.
Can you expand
on it?